# Plot using surf/mesh command in GNU octave

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab, octave

I want to plot a 3D plane in GNU Octave using the surf/mesh command.

I have following data e.g

a= [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17];

b= [ 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011];

c= [ -0.88 -8.87 -0.86 -0.82 -0.77 -0.71 -0.66 -0.62 -0.57 -0.54 -0.50 -0.47 -0.44 -0.42 -0.39 -0.377 -0.36 -0.89 -0.88 -0.85 -0.81 -0.76 -0.71 -0.66 -0.61 -0.57 -0.53 -0.50 -0.47 -0.44 -0.42 -0.39  -0.37 -0.36];

I could plot it using plot3 command..

But how should I plot it by using surf/mesh command in GNU Octave?

Comment: Is this really a math question or an Octave question?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, and I must say the results looks better than I expected:

```
a= [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17];
b= [ 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011];
c= [ -0.88 -8.87 -0.86 -0.82 -0.77 -0.71 -0.66 -0.62 -0.57 -0.54 -0.50 -0.47 -0.44 -0.42 -0.39 -0.377 -0.36 -0.89 -0.88 -0.85 -0.81 -0.76 -0.71 -0.66 -0.61 -0.57 -0.53 -0.50 -0.47 -0.44 -0.42 -0.39 -0.37 -0.36];
b_integer = 1000*b;
x = min(a):max(a);
y = min(b_integer):max(b_integer);
Z = zeros(numel(x),numel(y));
[X, Y] = ndgrid(x,y);
for i = 1:length(a)
    Z(a(i)==x,b_integer(i)==y)=c(i);
end
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

Note that this was done in Matlab.